# ng2-bootstrap. Errors during e2e tests

Tags: ng2-bootstrap

Trying to run e2e tests for ng2-bootstrap and have a couple of issues. Interested if this is jut me or not.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Download the latest from
   https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap
2. run `npm-install`
3. run `npm run build`
4. run `npm run link`
5. and finally run `nmp run e2e`

On the first run I got an error: `SpecReporter is not a constructor` which I was able to fix by replacing `const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');` in protractor.conf.js to `const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;`

But than there's another error: `Cannot find namespace 'webdriver'` which I can't figure out how to fix.

So if someone could just repeat these steps above an let me know if you're getting the same results I would really appreciate it.

I have created an issue on github about this: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1665

Answer (score 0):

try `import * as webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';`